# jquery -- $(this) does not apply to newly created elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i do have a from, something like if i asking you how many references you got. first you select from dropdown menu gender, then related textboxes come visible..

```
$("#select").change(function(){             
        var type = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        $("input").hide().filter("." + type).show();
        $(":button").show();
        });
```

then, you might have a second reference to add, you simply press add button to add another reference..

```
    var initial=0;
            function addReference(){
                var newDiv= addNewDiv();
                var htcontents="<select id=\'new\'>" +
                    "<option value=\'\'>--choose--</option>
                     <option value=\'article\'>article</option>
                     <option value=\'thesis\'>thesis</option>"
                      + "<input class=\'article\' type=\'textbox\' name=\'ref_author_name[]\'/>" 
                      + "<input class=\'article\' type=\'textbox\' name=\'ref_article_title[]\'/>"  
                      + "<input class=\'thesis\'  type=\'textbox\' name=\'ref_author_name[]\'/>" 
                      + "<input class=\'thesis\'  type=\'textbox\' name=\'ref_thesis_title[]\'/>";
                      document.getElementById(newDiv).innerHTML=htcontents;
            }
            function addNewDiv(){
                initial=initial+1;
                var ni = document.getElementById('area');
                var newdiv=document.createElement('div');
                var divIdName = 'Div #' +initial;
                newdiv.setAttribute('id', divIdName);
                ni.appendChild(newdiv);
                return divIdName;
            } // i guess there is a more simple solution with jQuery, but i do not know..
```

my problem is, when you add 2nd reference and select an option, visible textboxes does not change. i guess this occurs because of jquery code i have,

```
var type = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
 $("input").hide().filter("." + type).show();
```

I guess i am not selecting as i should, any ideas?

any help is deeply appreciated..

here is the fiddle : http://goo.gl/Xdjtc

Comment: Not quite sure what the problem is. `$("#select").change(function(){` will bind an event handler to the element with ID `select` which exists *at that moment*. It does not affect any select elements added later (IDs have to be unique anyway).

Comment: thanks Felix, but how to select newly added selects?

Comment: Either you use event delegation, as @will shows below, or you just bind the event handler to the newly created element.

Comment: Also note that `textbox` is not a valid value for the `type` attribute of an `<input>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you're not closing the `<select>` in your htcontents string.

As I understand it, you want to add the second reference using JavaScript. In order to bind an event handler to this newly created select, you need to use the [.on()](http://jqapi.com/#p=on) function, which automagically works on elements which are created after the line was executed on pageload.

Then you might mix up the id "#select" and the element "select". The second reference is not matched by your selector. You should use a class like `.my-selectbox` (using a better name than this of course) instead of an id, as you have multiple elements that should behave the same and be matched by your selector.

For further help, it would help, if you could provide a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/ or https://tinker.io/. That way someone could better understand what you are trying to do and fix your code if necessary.

Hope it helps.

Edit based on your jsfiddle: Try if this is what you are looking for: [Updated version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3dx9/4/). You should not be using an ID twice or more times, it meant to be unique. Use classes instead.

If you are using Firefox, check [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and maybe [the console API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API). It really helps debugging your code. For other browsers (Safari, Chrome) there are similar web developer tools that also provide a console. Debug your objects like this:

```
console.debug(myObject);
```

Comment: thank you Wolfram.. you are totally right, i was missing to end the select tag. how will i let you know after fiddle creation?

Comment: You could just edit your question and add the link to jsfiddle.

Comment: hi Wolfram. thank you very much. i dig out myself a bit, asked another questions here, and at last i have solution. cheers..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .delegate() (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or .on() (http://api.jquery.com/on/)

e.g:

```
    $("form").on('select','change',function(){             
            var type = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
            $("input").hide().filter("." + type).show();
            $(":button").show();
    });
```

The reason is that as far as javascript is concerned those newly created elements don't exist. Using delegate or on create bubbling events that will apply to existing and future elements.

Hope that helps :)